# Matlab interpolation : actif contour detector

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I try to code a snake actif contour detector under matlab. this is my code so far :

```
function contour_actif (Image, nombre_point)

[M N]=size(Image);
Image=rgb2gray(Image);

imshow(Image);
hold on;
[x,y] = ginput(nombre_point);

t = linspace(0,1,nombre_point);
ti = linspace(0,1,10*nombre_point);
x = spline(t,x,ti);
y = spline(t,y,ti);

alpha = 5;
beta = 0.5;
gamma = 1;
iterations = 50;

N = length(x);
a = gamma*(2*alpha+6*beta)+1;
b = gamma*(-alpha-4*beta);
c = gamma*beta;
P = diag(repmat(a,1,N));
P = P + diag(repmat(b,1,N-1), 1) + diag(   b, -N+1);
P = P + diag(repmat(b,1,N-1),-1) + diag(   b,  N-1);
P = P + diag(repmat(c,1,N-2), 2) + diag([c,c],-N+2);
P = P + diag(repmat(c,1,N-2),-2) + diag([c,c], N-2);
P = inv(P);

Image = double(Image);
[Gx,Gy] = gradient(Image);
f = sqrt(Gx.^2+Gy.^2);
[Gxx Gyy]= gradient(f);

for i = 1:iterations
    coords = [x,y];    
    fex = griddedInterpolant(Gxx , 'linear')
    fey = griddedInterpolant(Gyy , 'linear')
    x = P*(x*gamma+fex);
    y = P*(y*gamma+fey);
end
plot([x;x(1)],[y;y(1)],'r')

hold off;

end
```

I get an error when i try to get the interpolation between the gradient image and the image.  coords = [x,y];
        fex = griddedInterpolant(Gxx , 'linear')
        fey = griddedInterpolant(Gyy , 'linear')
        x = P*(x*gamma+fex);
        y = P*(y*gamma+fey);

Any help please.

Comment: Please post error message and also specify the code which has issue.

Comment: Undefined function 'plus' for input arguments of type 'griddedInterpolant'.

Error in contour_actif (line 40)
    x = P*(x*gamma+fex);